# Bash Script Parse HTML file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm using a shell script to get the tracking information for a FedEx package.  When I execute the script, I pass in the tracking number(a dummy number I found on the internet), and use curl:

```
#$1=797843158299
curl -A Mozilla/5.0 -b cookies -s "https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/WTRK/index.html?action=track&action=track&action=track&tracknumbers=$1=1490" > log.txt
```

The output from the curl command is the HTML code, and the information I need is between the tag line:

```
<!--TRACKING CONTENT MAIN-->
<div id="container" class="tracking_main_container"></div>
```

Within the  part is where I need to parse out the delivery information.
I am fairly new to scripting, and have tried some "| sed" suggestions I found online, but couldn't get anything to work.

Comment: I can see the html output of curl. What exactly should be the output/result of your script?

Comment: Probably the most robust approach is to use php's DOM parser. Though page scraping is always flaky.

Comment: Sorry? The `tracking_main_container` div is *empty*. Parsing its contents would give you an empty string. When the page is run in a browser, it's JavaScript that populates that div, and you're absolutely not going to be able to execute javascript from native bash without third-party tools.

Comment: ...now, if you want some suggestions re: such 3rd-party tools, I'd suggest using PhantomJS -- which will mean doing your scripting in JavaScript rather than bash.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with `curl` or `wget` because the rendering final page is created with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). It is possible to use another tools that are javascript capable like [spynner](/questions/tagged/spynner) in [python](/questions/tagged/python) or [phantomjs](/questions/tagged/phantomjs)

This is a full working example to check if the status is **delivered** or not :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1"

import spynner
from lxml import etree

browser = spynner.Browser(user_agent = useragent)
browser.create_webview(False)
browser.load("https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/WTRK/index.html?action=track&action=track&action=track&tracknumbers=797843158299")
browser.wait_load()

reddit = etree.HTML(browser.html)

try:
    print reddit.xpath('//div[@class="statusChevron_key_status bogus"]')[0].text
except:
    print "Undelivered"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Delivered
```

Comment: If you're going to make an answer with the same information I already provided in a comment, you might as well try to make it a reasonably informative answer -- providing specific suggestions of non-bash tools that could provide JavaScript execution, f'rinstance. I've already suggested PhantomJS on that count.

Comment: Just edited with [tag:spynner] in the same time of your comment

Comment: Bravo! Much more useful now. (I've been trying to do the same with Phantom, but was hitting a TypeError in Fedex's TrackingRootView minified js).